# How to create a checkbox for each possible enum value in Windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, dialog

Say we have an `enum Identifier {Name, Id, Number}` and we want to provide user with a message like dialog with only checkboxes for each possible `Identifier` value and Ok button. On dialog confirmation get a `List<Identifier>`(empty if none of the checkboxes was selected). How to do such simple thing with winforms?

Comment: What did you try so far? (You definitly won't need reflection, so maybe remove this tag?)

Comment: @LinusCaldwell maybe I'm brain-farting, but how would you do this without reflection? Apart from manually creating each checkbox, I mean.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Hmm, maybe I'm wrong, but I would not call it reflection if you do it like in rclement's answer, would you?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell nope, brainfart on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a array of values in your enum with:

```
var valuesArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Identifier));
```

To display the checkboxes:

```
foreach (var val in valuesArray)
{
    //create checkbox
    var cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Name = string.Format("cb_{0}", val);
    cb.Text = val; //set your properties

    //add to your form controls
    this.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

To get the list, just get all checkboxes on the form:

```
var checkedIdentifiers = new List<Identifier>();
foreach (var val in valuesArray)
{
    //find checkbox
    var cb = this.Controls[string.Format("cb_{0}", val)];
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        checkedIdentifiers.Add((Identifier)Enum.Parse(typeof(Identifier), val));
}
```

You can additional error checking to the above, but that is the gist of it.